# Change the icon used by v-toolbar-side-icon?

Tags: vuetify.js

Is it possible to change the icon used in by `v-toolbar-side-icon` to a custom one?

```html
    <template>
      <v-toolbar>
        <v-toolbar-side-icon></v-toolbar-side-icon>
        <v-toolbar-title>Title</v-toolbar-title>
        <v-spacer></v-spacer>
        <v-toolbar-items class="hidden-sm-and-down">
          <v-btn flat>Link One</v-btn>
          <v-btn flat>Link Two</v-btn>
          <v-btn flat>Link Three</v-btn>
        </v-toolbar-items>
      </v-toolbar>
    </template>
```

There is no props or documentation for that component itself in https://next.vuetifyjs.com/en/components/toolbars

Comment: I think you can just pass `v-icon` to a default slot like so: `<v-toolbar-side-icon><v-icon>search</v-icon></v-toolbar-side-icon>`. Does that behave properly? I haven't looked into it yet.

Comment: I found you can actually put the icon image       `<v-toolbar-side-icon>
        <img src="./assets/logo.png" />
      </v-toolbar-side-icon>` too late in the day to write out the full answer.

Comment: @Traxo that does not work

Comment: @Learner see answer. Perhaps I misunderstood something?

Answer (score 19):

`<v-toolbar-side-icon>` has been deprecated in [Vuetify 2.0](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/releases/tag/v2.0.0-beta.0)

Please use `<v-app-bar-nav-icon></v-app-bar-nav-icon>` instead.

Answer (score 14):

**EDIT:**
This solution was initially for `Vuetify` **v1**. See other answer for **v2**.

---

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GPRvMe)

Use custom `v-icon` in `v-toolbar-side-icon`'s default slot

```
<v-toolbar-side-icon>
  <v-icon>more_vert</v-icon>
</v-toolbar-side-icon>
```

Comment: List of icons names can be found at [material.io/tools/icons](https://material.io/tools/icons)

Comment: v-toolbar-side-icon has been deprecated in favor of v-app-bar-nav-icon in Veutify 2.0 (see below answer) - while working through my noob tutorial this was my experience.

Answer (score 3):

At this time, you can change it the by doing this:

```
<v-app-bar-nav-icon>
          <v-icon>mdi-database</v-icon>
        </v-app-bar-nav-icon>
```

Where `<v-icon>mdi-database</v-icon>`  is which icon i want to display instead the default one.

The result must be :
[Change vuetify app-bar-nav-icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LNvhd.png)

Hope it can help you.

Answer (score 1):

For me, it only works if I add the icon prop:

```
<v-app-bar-nav-icon icon >  
<v-icon color = "red">mdi-database</v-icon>
</v-app-bar-nav-icon>
```

Answer (score 0):

For the users who uses mdi, the icon is

```
<v-icon>mdi-menu</v-icon>
```

And here is the link of the [reference](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/icons/)

(vuetify version 2.5.6)

Hopefully, this answer could help the developer who faced similar issues as I did.

Comment: While this is helpful to the question, having an answer that is a bit more specific to the over all goal of the OP would probably be better for your SO rep.